# python importing src/package.module in setup.py

Tags: python, code-coverage, setup.py

I have following directory structure of a python package i want to build (python3.4)

````
```
/project/src/mypackage/__init__.py
/project/src/mypackage/module.py
/project/src/mypackage/setup_utils.py
/project/setup.py
```
````

I have some useful code within `setup_utils.py` that i want to import at the top of `setup.py`. If I don't add `sys.path.append('src')`, I get `ImportError`

````
```

$ cat setup.py

from setuptools import setup
from mypackage import setup_utils
cmdclass = setup_utils.cmdcass
...

$ python setup.py install
...
ImportError: No module named 'mypackage'
...
```
````

Now, If I do add `sys.path.append('src')`, I don't get coverage `Coverage.py warning: Module mypackage was previously imported, but not measured.`

````
```
$ cat setup.py

import sys
sys.path.append('src')
from setuptools import setup
from mypackage import setup_utils
cmdclass = setup_utils.cmdcass
...

$ python setup.py install
$ coverage ...
Coverage.py warning: Module mypackage was previously imported, but not measured.

```
````

So, what is the right approach to fix this?

Comment: You don't want to import a ton of code into setup.py.  Setup.py has to run to install your program. You won't have any of your prerequisites installed when that happens.  This can turn into a mess.

Comment: One example of such package is `pyautogui` that can't be installed before all the dependencies are installed (in a separate pass), and can't be installed in a headless mode at all. All of that because its `setup.py` imports the `pyautogui` module to read the version, while `pyautogui/__init__.py` imports a ton of code, ranging from dependencies that may not yet be installed, to stuff that checks if there's an X display available, raising an exception if not.

Answer (score -3):

I believe your problem is identified here: [Importing files from different folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4383571/importing-files-from-different-folder)

Basically, python only looks for modules within your current working directory. Since `/src` is not a module, it doesn't continue looking further.

Once possible solution is to turn the `/src` directory into a module, and then `setup_utils` can be a submodule within it. In order to turn `src` into a module, simply add an empty `__init__.py` file.

Then you can import it in your script as `from src.mypackage import setup_utils`